# move spaces from right to left in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, space

sorry for the noob question and for my bad english (it isn't my first language) but i don't know a way to move spaces from right to left in a string.

here an example:

```
SELECT 
VALUE_I_NEED = STR(<TABLE>.<FIELD>,6)
FROM <TABLE>
```

And the result is '20____' but i need '____20' (where '_' are spaces)

How can i have what i need?

Thank you in advance

M.

Comment: Do you want to pad spaces in front of a column value?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty strange requirement. This kind of thing should probably be done in the front end as it is formatting but you can use sql to do it.

Something like this.

```
declare @Something varchar(20) = '20     '

select replicate(' ', DATALENGTH(@Something) - LEN(@Something)) + RTRIM(@Something) as x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will add `6 SPACES`

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(20)
SET @Text = '20      '

SELECT RIGHT(SPACE(6) + RTRIM(@Text),20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can right pad the value by doing:

```
select right(replicate(' ', 6) + cast(<TABLE>.<FIELD> as varchar(6)), 6)
```